# Error Code 1215: cannot add foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am doing an assignment in SQL and I'm trying to add a foreign key on the `total` table referencing the `donuts` table.

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE DONUTS (
DonutID integer not null unique,
Donut_name varchar(35) not null,
Description varchar(35) not null,
Donut_Qty integer not null, 
Donut_price decimal not null,
PRIMARY KEY(DonutID, Donut_Qty, Donut_price));

CREATE TABLE TOTAL (
LINE_TOTAL Decimal NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Donut_Qty integer NOT NULL,
Donut_price decimal NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LINE_TOTAL),
FOREIGN KEY (Donut_Qty) REFERENCES donuts(Donut_Qty),
FOREIGN KEY (Donut_price) REFERENCES donuts(Donut_price));
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error Code 1215: cannot add foreign key constraint

I've checked that the DB engines are the same, and the character sets, and the data types.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE DONUTS (
    DonutID integer not null unique,
    Donut_name varchar(35) not null,
    Description varchar(35) not null,
    Donut_Qty integer not null, 
    Donut_price decimal not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(DonutID, Donut_Qty, Donut_price)
);    

CREATE TABLE TOTAL (
    LINE_TOTAL Decimal NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    DonutID integer not null, Donut_Qty integer NOT NULL,
    Donut_price decimal NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (LINE_TOTAL),
    FOREIGN KEY (DonutID, Donut_Qty, Donut_price) REFERENCES DONUTS(DonutID, Donut_Qty, Donut_price)
);
```

Your composite primary key in the DONUTS table has three fields: DonutID, Donut_Qty, Donut_price. The three fields that make up the composite keys suppose to be referenced in the TOTAL table.

Answer (score 0):

> Mysql requires an explicit unique key (or primary key) on any column
>   referenced as a foreign key in another table.

please refer this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

You are providing `non primary key` as `foreign key` which is not going to work.